# How to set Validator to custom form control in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I want to set validators to exact control in formGroup from outside of custom control component:

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg">
    <custom-control formControlName="custom">
    </custom-control>
</form>
```

```js
this.fg = this.fb.group({
      custom: [null,Validator.required]
});
```

This the custom control component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-control',
  template: `
  <mat-form-field>
        <input [formControl]="inputFormControl" />
        <mat-error 
           *ngIf="inputFormControl.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["custom-control.component.scss"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting: CustomControlComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  inputFormControl: new FormControl();
  onChange = (quantity) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(quantity: number) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {}
}
```

How can this required error be displayed? and What if I set aother validator through fg.get('custom').setValidator(XXX) ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `mat-error`:

- the `mat-error` element needs to be in a `mat-form-field` with the `input` which is throwing the error
- the FormControl that is physically in the `mat-form-field` must be the *exact* FormControl which is validated

In your current state of affairs, you need to add a `mat-form-field` around your `custom-control` and place the `mat-error` in there with it as opposed to having the `mat-error` *inside* `custom-component`.

Comment: Yes, mat-error and input should both be contained in the mat-form-field,  This is just a pseudocode

Comment: Question is, how do I set validator to the custom control through formGroup? Didn't find other effective answers except using Input() to pass the validator into the inner of the custom control component.

Answer (score -1):

implement Validator interface and provide NG_VALIDATORS

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'custom-control',
  template: `
        <input [formControl]="inputFormControl" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="inputFormControl.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["custom-control.component.scss"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting: CustomControlComponent
    },
    {
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomControlComponent),
        multi: true,
    },
  ]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

  inputFormControl: new FormControl();
  onChange = (quantity) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(quantity: number) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {}

  onValidatorChange = () => {
  };

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidatorChange = fn;
   }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.inputFormControl.invalid ? { internal: true } : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems not work for me